# PHP ftp_fput() logs an error "The system cannot find the file specified." when trying to upload an open file to a remote ftp server

Tags: php, centos8

I've got a PHP file that uploads a CV submitted via html form to a ftp server, but I cannot figure out how to specify the path, it seems. It comes back with error:

**ftp_fput(): The system cannot find the path specified.  in /var/www/*****/phpmailer/sendmail.php on line 288**

The code looks like this:

```
$finalCV = $id_nr . "." . $ext;
//
$location = "uploads/" . $finalCV;

//This next line was added to move the uploaded file to a folder on the local webserver,
//but now we would rather upload it directly to the ftp server
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['applCV']['tmp_name'], $location);

//Move uploaded & renamed CV to RES01
if($fp = fopen($location, 'r'))
  echo "File Open Successful. ";
  else {
    echo "File Open Unsuccessful. ";
  }

if($conn_id = ftp_connect("theftpserver"))
  echo "FTP Connection Established Successfully. ";
else {
  echo "FTP Connection Failed. ";
  }

$ftpuser = "wynand";
$ftppasswd = "*******";

if($login = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpuser, $ftppasswd)) {
  echo "FTP Login Successful. ";
}
 else {
   echo "FTP Login Unsuccessful. ";
 }

if(ftp_fput($conn_id, $somefile, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
  echo "Successfully uploaded CV. ";
}
  else {
    echo "There was a problem uploading CV. ";
  }
```

Comment: Don't have time to write an answer, but you are expected to go to the correct dir by using [`ftp_chdir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-chdir.php) and then use the filename only in `ftp_fput`

Comment: Thanks, but there's no change of directory required on the ftp side - when you log into the ftp server you are already in the directory the file should go into?

Comment: Where are you even defining `$somefile`? Also, `$fp` should be the locale_filename, not a handle to a file.

Comment: Sorry that was part of my experimentation. Thanks for your help - I will look into that, for now I've made a workaround with lftp and cron to sync that folder to the ftp server.

Comment: Have you tried turning the connection to the passive mode using the `ftp_pasv` function ?